# Find document based on field value on single subdocument in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose collection called WorkoutUser with the following simplified schema:

```
const WorkoutUserSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  exercises: [{
    exercise: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Exercise',
    },
    sets: [// not important],
    date: Date, // <- important
  }],
});
```

For reasons I won't get into here, I'd like to query the WorkoutUser collection to find all instances of a workout tied to the current user that is prior to the current workout. The date is not defined on the WorkoutUser for other reasons that aren't relevant here, but the date on each exercise will be the same.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
const workouts = await db.WorkoutUser
        .find({
          _id: { $ne: workout._id },
          user: workout.user,
          'exercises.exercise': exercise.exercise,
          'exercises.exercise.date': { $lt: userWorkout.date }, // <- relevant line
        });
```

This does not work currently. Is there a way to basically search on the date for `exercises.exercise[0].date`?

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, actually `exercise` and `date` both are at the same level so you can modify your query like this

```
const workouts = await db.WorkoutUser
        .find({
          _id: { $ne: workout._id },
          user: workout.user,
          'exercises.exercise': exercise.exercise,
          'exercises.date': { $lt: userWorkout.date }, // <- relevant line
        });
```

Comment: This was it, turns out I was just blind and misread which level it was at -- thanks!